# Shanks's Babystep Giantstep Algorithm running time BigO

Tags: cryptanalysis

I am working through Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography and am not in school anymore, so I don't have any advisers or peers to ask (my background is a BS in math). In the text they present the Shanks's BS-GS Algotrithm with a proof. I am having trouble figuring out how the total running time of the algorithm follows from the running time its parts.

The algorithm says to create two lists which each have length $n$. I understand how this ends up being about $2 \cdot n$ multiplications. Then they say comparing the lists takes $\operatorname{BigO}[\log(n)]$ steps and then jump straight to "hence the total running time is $\operatorname{BigO}[n \cdot \log(n)]$." Since the steps are done separately, why do we multiply instead of add the running times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, the elements of the full group conceptually end up in an $n\times n$ table, and the comparison of the column (giant step list) must be done on every row of length $n$ since the overlap of the lists is in a single unique row (which allows you to determine the answer you're looking for, e.g., discrete log uniquely). So you repeat the comparison at worst $n$ times, on average $(n+1)/2$ times until you find a collision.

The presentation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) is quite good, their $m$ being your $n$ since your listsize $n$ is $\lceil \#G \rceil$, so roughly the square root of the size of the group.

Comment: Just to be clear. Every time I take one of my "giant step" elements and compare it to my "baby step" elements, that requires [\log(n)]$ steps. Since  I do that about (n+1)/2 times, I will arrive at BigO[n⋅log(n)].  If this is the case, why is the number of operations for compiling my lists relevant if the comparisons take significantly more steps.

Comment: Well, as part of proving the overall complexity, you need to add all components and then take the largest term for the $O(\cdot)$ estimate, that's why. Since I have no idea what the notes you're referring to say exactly, this is all I can say.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I checked for references to my text and found that the section I am reading actually has an error, the correction clears up the confusion. The text is "Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography" by Hoffstein (page 80).

Comment: OK, you can upvote and accept the answer now if you wish :-)